# How to set 2d array as parameter for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, data-driven-tests, parameterized-unit-test

If expected variable is integer, it simply goes like this

```
[DataRow(2)]
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod(int expected)
{
      // some code...
}
```

But what should one do when there is 2d array int[,] instead of int parameter?
When I try to do this

```
[DataRow(new int[,] { {0, 0}, {0, 0} })]
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod(int[,] expected)
{
      // some code...
}
```

error says

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Comment: So what happened when you run the second code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve it by using [`DynamicData Attribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.dynamicdataattribute?view=mstest-net-1.2.0) like below:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(TestDataMethod), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void TestMethod1(int[,] expected)
{
    // some code...
    var b = expected;
}

static IEnumerable<object[]> TestDataMethod()
{
    return new[] { new[] { new int[,] { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 } } } };
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I've just updated my answer with the expected result image, Please take a look @Andrey

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)